# Узнать какая машина пришла первой JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь разобраться в ООП Js по книге Js для детей. И стало интересно, вот создал я 2 переменные которые отрисовываются машинами (tesla,nissan), и сделал так чтобы при условии когда переменная достигает конца экрана, выводилось сообщение "Финиш".

А как сделать чтобы узнать какая из них приехала первой? Должно быть "Финиш `this` машина приехала первой". Но я так и не понял как это сделать.

```js
var Car = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.draw();
};

Car.prototype.draw = function() {
  var carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

  this.carElement = $(carHtml);

  this.carElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

  $('body').append(this.carElement);
};

Car.prototype.moveRight = function(distance) {
  this.x += distance;
  this.carElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });
  if (this.x >= $('html').innerWidth()) {
    tesla.x = 0;
    nissan.x = 0;
    console.log('Первый финишировал ')
  }
};

var tesla = new Car(0, 20);
var nissan = new Car(0, 100);

$('.start').click(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    tesla.moveRight(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
    nissan.moveRight(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
  }, 30);
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start">Старт / ускорение</button>
<button class="stop">Стоп</button>
```

Comment: как вариант, сравнить координаты двух машин, и в модель Car добавить поле Title...и выводить title, у которого x больше

Comment: `moveRight` не должен проверять условие победы одной из машин, это не правильно с точки зрения архитектуры

Comment: у вас это можно решить, просто добавив в модель название машины...и дописать `alert('Первый финишировал' + this.title)`

Comment: @ThisMan а то, что `moveRight` в принципе оперирует объектами `nissan` и `tesla` вас не смущает?

Comment: конечно смущает, это как бы подразумевалось под _проверять условие победы одной из машин_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Car = function(x, y, title){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.title = title;
  this.draw();
};

Car.prototype.draw = function(){
  const carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

  this.carElement = $(carHtml);

  this.carElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });

  $('body').append(this.carElement);
};

Car.prototype.moveRight = function(distance){
  this.x += distance;
  this.carElement.css({
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });
};


const tesla = new Car(0, 20, 'tesla');
const nissan = new Car(0, 100, 'nissan');

let speed = 5; // Это будет скорость, с которой движутся машины.
let startInterval = null; // Здесь будет храниться setInterval.

const checkWinner = (car1, car2) => {
  if(car1.x >= $('html').innerWidth()){
    return car1;
  } else if (car2.x  >= $('html').innerWidth()) {
    return car2;
  }
  
  return null;
}

const stopRace = () => {
  clearInterval(startInterval);
  startInterval = null;
}

const endRace = () => {
  speed = 5;
  stopRace();
}

$('.start').click(function() {
  // Увеличиваем скорость через переменную, а не создавая новые интервалы.
  if (startInterval !== null) {
    return speed += 1;
  }
  startInterval = setInterval(function () {
    // Проверяйте условие здесь, а не в методе moveRight.
    const winner = checkWinner(tesla, nissan);
    if (winner) {
      alert(`Победитель: ${winner.title}`);
      tesla.x = 0;
      nissan.x = 0;
      return endRace();
    }

    tesla.moveRight(Math.floor(Math.random() * speed));
    nissan.moveRight(Math.floor(Math.random() * speed))
  }, 16);
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  stopRace();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start">Старт / ускорение</button>
<button class="stop">Стоп</button>
```

Ну а дальше, раз вы изучаете ООП, то можно уже написать и класс `Race`, куда перенести методы по старту/паузе гонки, проверки победителя и так далее. Можно этому классу передавать список машин, что бы не завязываться на переменные `tesla`, `nissan`. 
Но это вам уже ДЗ;)

Comment: Только не понятно почему после финиша, машины ставятся на исходную позицию с погрешностью до 5 пикселей?

Comment: мой косяк, там нужно `return endRace()` в условии `if(winner)`